# Flot draw additional vertical grid line

Tags: flot

I can't get rid of vertical line in the end of graph.

I have replicated problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/63BPw/4/

Color of grid lines is **darkred** and it's setted only in this part of js code:

```
grid: {
    aboveData: false,
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: true,
    color: "darkred",
    borderWidth: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 1,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    }
}
```

Console do not throw any errors. I don't use any margins from inside javascript file or external css files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is probably a bug.

The problem isn't in your grid setup, but in the drawing of each axis.  Specifically, you setup 2 y-axes, one on the left and one on the right.  Deep in the flot code, it decides whether to draw a "bar" to attach the ticks to based on whether the axis is the "innermost" or not.  When you have 2 yaxes, it is incorrectly deciding that your right-positioned yaxis is *not* innermost, and therefore drawing a tick bar.

Relevant code, both bits are called per-axis:

In `allocateAxisBoxFirstPhase`:

```
/*note this is only called for axes that have tickLength set
  but later it is checked as true/false, not undefined 
  (which is what you'd get if you set your yaxis tickLength = 0) */
var sameDirection = $.grep(all, function (a) {
  return a && a.reserveSpace;
});

innermost = $.inArray(axis, sameDirection) == 0;
```

In `drawGrid`:

```
if (!axis.innermost) {

   //in here it draws the tick bar

}
```

**Workaround**:

Find that `!axis.innermost` bit and change it to `axis.innermost == false`.  Set tickLength = 0 in your 2nd yaxis.  That's it.

I've implemented those two changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/63BPw/5/

Also, FYI I filed a bug about this: https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1056

Comment: And the bug has already been fixed, better than I suggested :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help and for pushing this issue to github.
I will download corrected version of flot now!